# Validating form data with image upload using multipart in Play framework 2 with scala

Tags: forms, scala, validation, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

i am working on user profile task in which i am getting user info and user profile pic from `Form`  in a mutlipart form

here is code

```
 def addNewUser = Action(parse.multipartFormData){
    implicit request =>
        val firstName =   request.body.dataParts.get("firstName").toString()
       val lastName  = request.body.dataParts.get("lastName").toString()
        val email = request.body.dataParts.get("email").toString()
        val password = request.body.dataParts.get("password").toString()

      request.body.file("picture").map{ picture =>
          import java.io.File
    val filename : String = picture.filename
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    log.debug("pic uploaded , : {} , {}" ,filename  )
     log.debug("pic uploaded , {}" ,  contentType)
     val config = ConfigFactory.load()
     var path = config.getString("path")
     var filepath = path.concat(filename)
    picture.ref.moveTo(new File(filepath))
          log.debug("sending response to u.i")
          val status = Http.Status.OK
       val json   = Json.obj("status" -> status , "msg" -> "Signup successfull")
          Ok(json)
        //----------
      }.getOrElse{
        BadRequest("error occured ")
      }
  }
```

Firstly i want to know that am i using right approach for getting the data part or is there any other efficient way of doing it?

plus i want to validate these form fields so how can i use validations in this situation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Form Validation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms) that Play Framework has will still work with multipart forms ([here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/34b3090525c4b550938121beb09f10072811b1f3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L83)).

```
case class Example(foo: String, bar: Option[String])
val myForm = Form(mapping("foo" -> text, "bar" -> optional(text))

def addNewUser = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  myForm.bindFromRequest(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded).fold(
    errors => { /* ... */ },
    data => {
      request.body.file("picture").map { /* ... */ }
      /* ... */
    }
  )
}
```

However if this is done often, you could create a [custom BodyParser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Combining-body-parsers) that composes the existing Multipart and Form parsers together.